# NDK build failed cocos2d-x

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

This errors comes while compiling project.android in cocos2d-x:
``` Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml 
make: Entering directory ``/home/maxim/project/cocos2d-x-3.5/Lesson1/proj.android'
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dcpp_shared <= HelloWorldScene.cpp
make: /home/maxim/project/android-ndk-r9d/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++: Command not found
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dcpp_shared/__/__/Classes/HelloWorldScene.o] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: Leaving directory ``/home/maxim/project/cocos2d-x-3.5/Lesson1/proj.android'
Ndk build failed! ```
What's problem?
**There is my .bashrc:**
`export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/home/maxim/project/cocos2d-x-3.5/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH`

`export COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT=/home/maxim/project/cocos2d-x-3.5/templates
export PATH=$COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT:$PATH`

`export NDK_ROOT=/home/maxim/project/android-ndk-r9d
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH`

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/maxim/android-sdks
 export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$PATH
 export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools:$PATH`

`export ANT_ROOT=/usr/share/ant/bin
 export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH`

Comment: `Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-16 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 9 in ./AndroidManifest.xml` 

this statement clearly indicates that you should change `android:minSdkVersion` to 16 in the manifest file

Comment: Does your file "arm-linux-androideabi-g++" exist under the NDK specified path?

Comment: @Nadarian: That is just a warning, not an error. Building should proceed regardless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thr error pertains to a missing toolchain in your NDK folder, from the build path I can see that you are using the r9D(at the time of writing) which may not contain the 4.8v toolchain. Check the folder again and then use the following command to build via a CLI

```
cocos compile -p android --ndk-toolchain arm-linux-androideabi-*
```

where * will be the version of the toolchain within the NDK folder folder.